# Is a non-interactive git add -p possible?

Tags: git

tl;dr: Is it possible to add only parts of file to git staging non-interactively?

I am writing a pre-commit hook to update version number and sync that up in a couple of files. These files absolutely cannot import version from the main version file.

I can already change and sync version numbers in all the files. However a couple of files contain other data too and I want to add only the lines with version info automatically to git in pre-commit.

I can get those line numbers. Is there a command/option/way to add those lines to git non-interactively? Because the pre-commit hook can of-course not be interactive.

Update: Looks like it has been already asked at stackoverflow.com/q/2783166 for anyone who happens to stumble on my question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2783166?

Comment: @arcyqwerty wow that's pretty involving stuff. Thanks for the link!

Comment: If you can confirm that solves your problem I'm going to go ahead and mark this as duplicate

Comment: @arcyqwerty feel free to mark this duplicate

Comment: Done. You should have a button to confirm it on your post. Otherwise, it'll take 5 close votes (mine included).